# Javascript libraries for drawing multilevel trees

Tags: javascript, tree

I would like to know about the available js libraries for drawing multilevel trees. Some functionalities I'd like to add to the created tree would be to make the nodes click-able and to be able to select an area on the graph and do actions based on the selection.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try arbor.js?

Comment: arbor.js is awesome when it comes to force-directed layouts. I'm not sure as to whether it can draw trees with top orientation.

Answer (score 0):

I'd check out [Protovis](http://vis.stanford.edu/protovis/ex/). I've had good success with it. However, it is a very general library, giving you lots of building blocks to make nice graphs, but it won't be a turnkey solution.